# How to find a player's redstone clock (or other aggressive circuitry)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone, minecraft-bukkit

I'm an admin for a minecraft server where I suspect one of the players has set up a fast cycle redstone circuit. The reason is the server uses what seems to me to be too high of cpu for only one or two players logged in, and lately there always seems to be a bit of lag.

I've found where he had built one before and he said that he wouldn't build one again, but knowing him, it's likely that he build one similar and not "exactly" like before.

So, are there any good ways to find where there is a redstone circuit like that, or better, is there a bukkit plugin that I can use to globally disable such circuits?

*edit*

Just to be clear, I'm not an op, I'm the full blown server admin (I pay for the VPS) lol. It's a windows server 2008 rc2 server so I have access to all files. It's currently running bukkit so that's why I would like to know about bukkit plugins that would make my life easier.

I did search for bukkit plugins but I couldn't find any "official" ones, which is why I asked for other unreleased or beta plugins. =)

Comment: Good question! I can't think of any vanilla solutions myself, but there is probably a Bukkit mod that allows you to do so.

Comment: You could load it in single-player and run around until it's chunk get loaded out to approximate it's location.

Comment: @Ullallullo: Consider that it could be underground.  He can't possibly think to find a circuit hidden well enough from someone trying to hide it.

Comment: I don't play Minecraft, so excuse my ignorance but... what's the problem with him building a redstone circuit? Does it just cause an undesirable amount of lag?

Comment: @Wipqozn:  The game uses a series of delay switches which could very well slow down the game in large quantities.  It's especially disruptive on servers where other players are trying to play as well.

Comment: @Neil: I know, that's why I didn't post it as an answer. ;)

Comment: Have you considered that it might be not a clock, but rather a long exposed Hopper trail? From what a friend told me, Hoppers are the worst when it comes to CPU resources.

Comment: @EgorHans This question was asked about 2 years before hoppers were added.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is now a Bukkit mod for detecting and teleporting to redstone clocks: the sensibly-named [Redstone Clock Detector](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/redstone-clock-detector/).

Answer (score 33):

If you have access to the world file you can use a [map editor/viewer](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Programs_and_editors#Mapping) to get a view of the map, and then do a filter just for redstone, overlay the second image and you will know where all the redstone is, it shouldn't take long to find the clock.

Comment: You make it sound like a bomb search.

Comment: @The Communist Duck - Well, it *is* ticking...

Comment: Which editor would you recommend?

Comment: @Kort I don't know, I try not to use them as it's sort of cheating... But anything with "x-ray" removes the need for the overlay but for the overlay method it needs to be 2D

Comment: @Kort It's really a matter of taste. Try a few mapping programs, see which ones are nice to use. In particular, look for the ability to render only specific block ids (i.e. redstone), although that's a pretty standard feature. [The wiki has an excellent list of mappers.](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Programs_and_editors#Mapping)

Answer (score 15):

If you don't have access to the world files or the server configuration, use a custom texture pack that makes all blocks except for the ones likely to be in the mechanism (e.g. redstone) semi-transparent. Then, it's a matter of walking around until you see it: even if it's underground.

You could do it fairly quickly by editing terrain.png in your own custom texture pack, but there are several texture packs that do the same thing (like, for example, [Strongestcraft](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/158611-16x166strongestcraftupdated-6-26-345-pm-cdt/)).

Comment: I would do that except this world is 130mb now and extends at least 2000 blocks in all directions from 0,0 so it's quite a ways to walk when you can't see what you're running into, lol.

Answer (score 6):

I can't believe no one commented on Opis, by Professor Moebius: http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/2104497-164server-admin-opis-112-alpha-now-with-entity-support/

This is a server side Forge (and client side for the admins) mod, and if you have option to use it (turn a vanilla server into a Forge one, or a Bukkit server into a MCPC Plus one), this is *THE* solution to this problem.

Opis is a Forge mod that allows to profile how much time is spent in each mod, chunk, even mob in the server. It shows the info as overlays over a modified open source minimap mod, and allows for tricks like teleport the admin to the close vicinity of a block or creature causing trouble, mark with a red transparent block the conflicting block, see what Forge mod causes the worst trouble... It works with vanilla or Forge modded blocks, so it can find poorly designed redstone clocks or hopper chains in a heartbeat anywhere in a server.

Direwolf20, a famous youtuber known for modded let's plays and mod reviews, made a video showing this mod:

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I know of any mod to do that, though I can suggest an alternative solution.  Tell him that you had suspicions and that you found it.  Tell him that either he downsizes it or that you'll destroy it completely.  He doesn't have to know you don't know where it is.

It's a bit of a bluff, but he'd have no reason to assume you wouldn't know where it is so it's a win-win situation.  If he says he'd downsize it and nothing changes, just ban him.

Comment: Maybe KortPleco would like to have proof before accusing one of his guests of anything.

Comment: That's evil! How could you?!

Comment: @Ronan: With a little bit of tact and a dash of sadism.

Comment: I did that before and discovered his clock that he had built some weeks ago. This one was nearby and more recent, which of course resulted in his ban. I'm still going to check for others though to be sure that things are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Move your server file into your single player and change the skin for all common solid block (dirt,stone,sand,sandstone) to be air and then you should be able to see the circuit underground.

Comment: You don't need to move the file to SP for that.

Comment: easier to find the skins

Comment: Skins work that work in SP work equally well in MP.

Answer (score 0):

If the the redstone clock has a lot of redstone torches, use [zombe's modpack](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/91055-v166-zombes-modpack-26-mods-v427-upd-17jun/)'s cheat function, which allows you to see through blocks. After installing the mod, copy [this file](http://cl.ly/241F2S041r0E1Z3W2x2W) to `{minecraft folder}/mods/zombe`. After you have done this, connect to the server and press <kbd>Y</kbd> and then <kbd>O</kbd>. This will show you all the redstone Torches(on/off). If you want to see through everything (etc. blocks), press and <kbd>K</kbd> (default is <kbd>I</kbd>, but I changed it for accessibility)

Note: The config file has colours set for different (redstone) items. Light red for redstone torch(on) and dark red for redstone torch(off).

---

If you don't have any redstone circuits that you value, use [WorldEdit](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit), and do this commands:

```
//hpos1 (at a location)
//hpos2 (at another far location diagonal from the original position)
//expand vert (Expands vertically 512 blocks)
//replace 55 0
```

Hopefully, you will be able to find and remove the redstone circuit (the wires). If not, try it at another location.

Since you are running Bukkit you may also want to restrict redstone by using [WorldGuard](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldGuard), and prevent lower-ranked users from placing and making such circuits.

Answer (score 0):

I would just Xray using the Nodus Xray (you can add custom blocks to show and to not show)
easy finding
does work if you remove ALL blocks that Orefuscator turns things into, using -xray del [ID]

Comment: Could you elaborate? Some people may not know what Nodus is. You should add a link.