# Minecraft command block logging

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-bukkit

I had just updated my friend's minecraft server to the beta build of bukkit (1.4.6 R0.1). This restored all of the plugins that weren't available when it was vanilla.

However, the internet (and its users) seem to hate me. Just after resolving most problems, I logged on. I keep on dying and dying and dying *continuously*. I narrowed the issue down to the Essentials `/kill` command. I used PluginManager to disable the command, and the dying stopped. Apparently someone put a command block on a clock, with the command set to `/kill werdnaminer` (me!).

Is there a way to log the triggering of command blocks? I need a way to locate and disable that clock without messing up what contraptions others have created.

**EDIT:** Looks like it was added in the 1.6 update! YAY! Thanks Mojang! (or was it Spigot or Bukkit?)
[image: Screenshot of server terminal]

**EDIT2:** Yup, it's Spigot. Boohoo.

Comment: At least it wasn't `/kill @a`.  Or was it?

Comment: It wasn't - my friend didn't have the problems.

Answer (score 10):

Only ops are able to program command blocks, so that should narrow the list of suspects. Some (virtual) face time with your ops should reveal the guilty party.

In the meantime, if your map doesn't rely heavily on command blocks, they can be disabled by setting `enable-command-block=false` in the `server.properties` file and restarting the server.

To locate the offending block you can render the world map showing just command blocks and redstone, using [one of the many 3rd-party cartography tools](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Programs_and_editors/Mapping#Mappers). (I quite like Minecraft Overviewer for this use, and though it's not technically 1.4.6-up-to-date, it can handle Anvil and custom block IDs so it's still compatible.) This will give you a high-level view of the problem and let you zero in on the possible culprits. Compare it to a regular overworld render to find a recognisable landmark nearby, then fly/tp there, unearth it, and render it inoperable.

Comment: Actually, in this private server, everyone is op. We kind of trust each other and being op allows us to have a little more fun. :-) Thanks for the idea - I'll download the map and try to locate it.

Comment: Actually, I found it using your solution: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25471/how-to-find-a-players-redstone-clock-or-other-aggressive-circuitry/28922#28922

Comment: @ascom If this answer has helped you, mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark on the side :)

Answer (score 1):

Command Block dont have the kill command inside.

all other things comes with Mods/Plugins

read this https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block and you know what the command block can do.

Comment: In bukkit essentials, (which is technically a mod) the /kill command can be used in a command block

Comment: Also, it can be used in a command block in recent minecraft versions